# Limits of two variables $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{u \rightarrow t} u^{\alpha} \sqrt{t-u} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

---

I want to find $\alpha>0$ to satisfy

$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{u \rightarrow t} u^{\alpha} \sqrt{t-u} = 0
$$

My intuitive guess is $\alpha$ must be less than $1/2$. But how to prove this rigorously?

---

Edit - I asked a sort of a dumb question.. I will post the original question.

Comment: Actually $\lim_{u \to t} u^{\alpha} \sqrt{t-u} = 0$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: Should that be $u \to t-$, or do you mean to take the limit in $\Bbb C$? (And if so in that latter case, what branch of the square root are you using?)